# Spyder Ipython Console - code to automatically print to pdf and save to HTML file

Tags: spyder

I am working in Spyder and would like to record the console output as either a html or pdf file. Currently the only way to achieve this is to right click on the console window and then choose 'save as'.

The problem with this approach is that the file path needs to be specified manually. It would be much more desirable to be able to set the working directory in the code and then save the pdf or html automatically to this location. Is this possible?

Or if this is not possible, is there any code that when the 'save as' option is right clicked, the file browser is opened on the current working directory?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder developer here*) My answer:

> Or if this is not possible, is there any code that when the 'save as' option is right clicked, the file browser is opened on the current working directory?

We can implement this in a future release. Please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) so we don't forget to do it in the future.

Comment: Hi Carlos, so there is not script or setting that can be used to automatically save the console as a html? Also, just to be sure, when I say the current working directory, I mean the working directory set in the code using rather than the file itself? i.e using os.chdir() within the working script?

Comment: Yeah, there's no way to save automatically save a session. And I don't see a problem with adjusting your current working directory. However, none if this functionality exists right now.